# npm won't recognize in gitlab-ci (working on a windows server runner)

Tags: npm, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, windows-server, gitlab-ci-runner

I am trying to do a simple ci on my windows server. (Windows2012R)
All my job script do is: `npm install`
And my pipeline input is:
`'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

The thing is, I know this output about not including node in my environment variables...
With a linux server I don't have this issue so I am guessing it is something considering me using a windows server...

Someone know what the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution, I have added the path to node *after* the runner process started. All I needed to do was stop the process and start it again...